# How to use .rosinstall files?

Tags: ros

I'm trying to build the rotors package {https://github.com/ethz-asl/rotors_simulator}

I followed the steps below.

-i need to install the dependencies using the .rosinstall files in the source of the RotorS package. but i can't figure how to do that.

```
$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src $ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ catkin_init_workspace  # initialize your catkin workspace 
$ wstool init
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ git clone git@github.com:ethz-asl/rotors_simulator.git
$ git clone git@github.com:ethz-asl/mav_comm.git
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/
$ catkin init  # If you haven't done this before.
$ catkin build
```

-I'm not sure how to use the files to install the dependencies. I read the documentation for rosinstall but I'm confused on which file to mention for path and URI. and how to install the packages.

- I'm sorry if this is a basic question, I'm new to ros and I don't know all the features, can someone help me with it?

PS: I'm using Ubuntu Focal with ROS noetic.

Comment: Thanks for asking this here. In the future it will be helpful if you provide a little bit more context on what you've tried and why/how it failed. This will let us know a little bit more about what your problem is instead of generically guessing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is to use: `rosinstall . <your_package>.rosinstall`

This answer will explain rosinstall clearly https://answers.ros.org/question/9213/how-exactly-does-rosinstall-work/